# How to retrieve specific value from XML API?

Tags: xml, excel, api

I have an API.

> http://eve-marketdata.com/api/item_history2.xml?char_name=demo&region_ids=10000002&type_ids=33468&days=2

I only want the "volume" value.

In Excel 2013, I used

```
=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE(API ADDRESS),"//row/@volume")
```

but I'm getting the `#VALUE!` error.

Can someone point me out what I'm doing wrong?

---

QUESTION:

When I put this formula in:

```
=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("http://eve-marketdata.com/api/item_history2.xml?char_name=demo&region_ids=10000002&type_ids=33468&days=2"), "//emd/result/rowset/row/@volume")
```

I get #VALUES!. I think the problem is coming from webservice function itself because When I put in this formula:

```
=WEBSERVICE(http://eve-marketdata.com/api/item_history2.xml?char_name=demo&region_ids=10000002&type_ids=33468&days=2)
```

I also get #VALUE!. Do you know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fine tune your Xpath query. Take a look at the XML the web service returns:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<emd version="2">
    <currentTime>2016-01-29 13:37:47</currentTime>
    <result>
        <rowset name="history" key="typeID,regionID,date" columns="typeID,regionID,date,lowPrice,highPrice,avgPrice,volume,orders">
            <row typeID="33468" regionID="10000002" date="2016-01-28" lowPrice="74500000.06" highPrice="76300002.15" avgPrice="76248999.69" volume="279" orders="219"/>
            <row typeID="33468" regionID="10000002" date="2016-01-29" lowPrice="74000000.89" highPrice="80449888.7" avgPrice="75000104.61" volume="101" orders="68"/>
        </rowset>
    </result>
</emd>
```

Your Xpath query needs to take you from the root of the document, to the value you are interested in, in a complete path, so you want:

```
//emd/result/rowset/row/@volume
```

Putting this all together, your formula should be:

```
=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("http://eve-marketdata.com/api/item_history2.xml?char_name=demo&region_ids=10000002&type_ids=33468&days=2"), "//emd/result/rowset/row/@volume")
```

Which gives you the result of 279 -- because it is only taking the first value.

To get both values, you would need to have multiple calls to the `FILTERXML` function, and adjust your Xpath to take this into account. If your doing this, I'd suggest moving the call to `WEBSERVICE` into it's own cell.

So, your final result may look something like:

```
=WEBSERVICE("http://eve-marketdata.com/api/item_history2.xml?char_name=demo&region_ids=10000002&type_ids=33468&days=2")
=FILTERXML(A1, "//emd/result/rowset/row[position()=1]/@volume")
=FILTERXML(A1, "//emd/result/rowset/row[position()=2]/@volume")
```

<sub>Note that `position()` starts counting from 1, for some reason.</sub>

Comment: does =FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("http://eve-marketdata.com/api/item_history2.xml?char_name=demo&region_ids=10000002&type_ids=33468&days=2"), "//emd/result/rowset/row/@volume") work on your excel? because i'm still getting #VALUE! I get an error from WEBSERVICE when I use it by getting #VALUE!

Comment: @user2521723 Can you edit the query into your question (and indent it by four spaces)? The comment markdown messes with it so I can't be sure what the problem is for you -- the example I gave at the bottom of the post works for me though in Excel 2013 (you just need to make sure they're on separate rows)

Comment: sorry. I put the question in my first question

Comment: @user2521723 When I run the first query you put in, I get the result. you expect -- on your second you've not enclosed the request in quotes. What happens if you try to navigate to [the result page directly](http://eve-marketdata.com/api/item_history2.xml?char_name=demo&region_ids=10000002&type_ids=33468&days=2)? Is it possible you're being blocked by something like a ratelimit?

Comment: I can navigate to the result page directly and I see all the data. I enclosed the website in quotation, and I still get the value error. I started up a new excel spreadsheet and the same error. If there a way to find out if i'm being ratelimit blocked? I can use DATA tab -> From Web and enter the query to look at the data.

Comment: @user2521723 If you're getting the data when you visit the web site, that's probably not the problem. I don't know what to suggest further. Perhaps try a different webservice request & check it's not Excel / Firewall getting in the way? What happens for `=WEBSERVICE("ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8")` for example?

Comment: ipinfo webservice works. arrg this is so frustrating. It seems that =WEBSERVICE is the problem but it's not returning the values :(